# If $A\in O_n(\mathbb{R})$ then $A^{-1}\in O_n(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to show that if $A\in O_n(\mathbb{R})$ then $A^{-1}\in O_n(\mathbb{R})$

$$A\in O_n(\mathbb{R})\iff A^{t}=a^{-1}$$

But how can I show that $A^{-1}\in O_n(\mathbb{R})$, if I look at $(A^t)^t$
I get that  $(A^t)^t=(A^{-1})^{-1}=A$

Comment: You can start by $AA^t=I$. Multiply by $A^{-1}$ to get $A^t=A^{-1}$. Now transpose to get $A=(A^t)^t=(A^{-1})^t$. Therefore, $I=AA^{-1}=(A^{-1})^tA^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $A\in O_n(\mathbb{R})$, we know that $A$ is invertible and $A^{-1}=A^t$.

To show that $A^{-1}\in O_n(\mathbb{R})$, we need to show that $A^{-1}$ is invertible and $(A^{-1})^{-1}=(A^{-1})^t$.

Now, $A^{-1}$ is invertible and $(A^{-1})^{-1}=A$ (this is true for any invertible matrix), so what is left to show is that $A=(A^{-1})^t$. Can you deduce this from $A^{-1}=A^t$?